# I have done some modelling but nothing appear wen rendering either on evee or cycles

Tags: rendering

[image]

this is the modelling viewport everything is okay however when rendering only the columns disappear
i have tried other parts of my project but everything works fine expect this part.
i have searched on youtube and internet and found those
In object mode press W --- clear all restricted render. That will make all objects visible in the render. ( when pressing w  it switch to select circle from the select box button)
Also, you can select an object and hit  Ctrl+Alt+H to un-restrict render on the selected object. (nothing happened)

iam using blender 2.93[image]

---

when i opened my laptop right now the file looked like this somehow dont know how they transformed like this. i dont know how to send the file here i cant see a attachment option [image]

Comment: Hi is there a way to share your file or those pillars? It would help to find it easier if you alone are not sure what you may have pressed or use

Comment: i dont know how to send the file here m however, it seems like a bug for me so i think i will re do it again i think